# Recreate application from memory snapshot

Tags: java, snapshot

How do I create a snapshot of running java application in order to be able to load the same snapshot later to recreate exactly the same state of running application? How do I load this snapshot?

EDIT

Application uses Event Sourcing, we have event log which can be replayed to get to a particular application state, however we'd like to archive the log and only retain the latest application state in a snapshot which we'd like to load instead of replaying all of the events from event log.

Comment: Please read some more books about computers and java's relation to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can serialize part of your data and deserialize it later on. Also, you need to think about common patterns (e.g. Command) and use them in your app. This will help you to do serialization of app's behavior or processing flow (even on half way of processing of data).

Comment: This sounds like the direction you wish to go in to store and restore application state. +1 for the Command shout.

Comment: Yes, that's right. For some reason i thought there would be a way to use some profiling tools to do that

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library from Martin Krasser which does exactly that - keeps state using event sourcing and also allows for event log snapshots: https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced